# Crashes from Updated/Released Production Core Data Models

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, app-store

**Background/issue:** I have a Core Data app in production and I just sent out an update where I added a couple of attributes in an existing entity without making a new model version (I didn't know this was a step). This is causing my user's apps to crash. The crash only happens when they first open the app after updating then it seems to work fine after the initial crash.

**How I think it can be fixed:** I'm thinking that I should go to a previous commit > copy the old data model > go back to master > delete the updated data model > drag and drop the copy into Xcode > then go to Editor to "Add Model Version". After add the new attributes I need I'm scared to do this and submit it to the App Store as it may cause more problems for people who already updated their app.

**Ask:** Is there a way I can revert my changes to the old data model version then make a new one from that? Without affecting my current users who already upgraded to the database version with errors?

I paused the phased release of this update to stop having users get crashes so if anyone knows how to fix this please help!

Comment: you can go for data migration it may resolve your problem check the below link   https://www.raywenderlich.com/7585-lightweight-migrations-in-core-data-tutorial